# What happens to the returned Arraylist by Collections.in modifiable list(), when the original list is modified?

Tags: java, collections

What happens to the returned Arraylist by Collections.in modifiable list(), when the original list is modified ?
Is it modified too ? Or it remains unchanged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) says it is an only readable view of the original list and because the collection returns always the same objects, the changes you made on the original list will also affect on the un-modifiable list view.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "Much SQL views?"

Comment: @AbhishekSingh what do you mean by your comment. If my answer solved your question please mark it as the correct answer. thanks